# Excel VBA - search the same column across all worksheets, looking for ANY data

Tags: excel, if-statement, worksheet, vba

i can do simple row deletions etc in single sheets in VBA, but this one has me stumped.

I need to search for ANY data (likely to be an email address, but in reality could be any text or number) in N1:N100, across all open worksheets...except Sheet1 (i.e. from Sheet2 to whatever the last open worksheet is)...

...if any data is found in the N1:N100 range for that particular worksheet (i.e. Sheet2) then do nothing and search the next worksheet (i.e. Sheet3)...if no data is found then enter "NONE" in cell N1 (on i.e. Sheet2) and then move onto the next worksheet (i.e. Sheet3).

Ive seen IF/ELSEIF/THEN code from other people, but it all seems to be sheet specific...and as i said im a bit out of my depth with this particular part.

This will feed into a larger bit of VBA code that ive got thats already spread over several sheets of A4, thought i had worked out all the bugs by now :D

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count

            ' Insert your code here.
            ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
            ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
            MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

         Next I

      End Sub
```

Or you can loop over all of the worksheets using a For Each loop:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop2()

         ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
         Dim Current As Worksheet

         ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
         For Each Current In Worksheets

            ' Insert your code here.
            ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
            MsgBox Current.Name
         Next

      End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Turtles, that second bit of codes seems the best to use, ill test it out over the weekend, much appreciated!